# Google returns blank for name when 'email' scope requested

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm making a service that runs over flask and uses OAuth for authentication.
My code is roughly same as things in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499286/using-google-oauth2-with-flask).
For now, I tried to request Google with scope 'email' as below:

```
def authorize(self):
        return redirect(self.service.get_authorize_url(
            scope = 'email',...
```

And then, I could get a response, the following is part of the response:

> ...u'name': u'', u'family_name': u'', u'email_verified': True, u'given_name': u''...

As you can see, names are just blank while I could get the email address as intended.
So, I'd like to know if there's any workaround to get the email and the name(s) at the same time.
Thank you in advance for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps want the `profile` scope too; the `email` scope only fills in the email address.

What profiles are available is listed in the [JSON API](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration); besides `email` and `profile`, there is also the `openid` scope (which is, I believe, a default). Also see the [Google Sign-in scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#authorization-scopes).

However, the `email` scope should already include the full name of the user, *provided they filled one in and are sharing it*.

Comment: Thank you, Martjin.
But, well, I could get names with some of my google accounts even I requested with 'email' only while rest of my accounts couldn't.

Comment: @laputan1: then those accounts don't want to give that info out or have not filled it in.

Comment: @Martjin, actually, those accounts are also mine. I made them for testing.They are supposed to be okay...