# Authenticating Users with Python OAuth 2

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, oauth2client

[Authenticate Users](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users)

I am using google bookshelf tutorial. I have done exactly what written there. But I am not able to run the application on my local server.

I tried adding `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in `config.py` but no help. Can someone please help me to understand this process.

When I am opening `http://localhost:8080/books/` this on chrome I am getting following error.

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
information, please see
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

It would be great help if I someone show me a working example of simply using oauth2client with flask and logging.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What I wanted in this stack overflow question [Flask Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499286/using-google-oauth2-with-flask)