# Google & Oauthlib - Scope has changed

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, django-1.7

I am using OAuthlib for conducting OAuth flow of Google. It was working well for 4 to 5 months. Suddenly I started getting below error:

```
File "/home/whitesnow-2/Gaurav/Axonator/AxVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", 
line 409, in validate_token_parameters raise w Warning: Scope has changed from 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" to 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile".
```

Below is the code for generating OAuth authorization URL:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
    redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
)
authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    access_type='offline',
    include_granted_scopes='true',
    prompt='consent'
)
```

Below is the code for Google OAuth callback:

```
auth_code = request.GET.get("code")
objectid = request.GET.get("state")
error = request.GET.get("error")
if error == "access_denied":
    return "Access Denied"
else:
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
        redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
    )
    flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
```

Comment: How strange that the "from" and "to" scopes are the exact same. Could this have been the result of a bug at Google's end?

Answer (score 23):

You can disable this warning by setting the `OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE` environment variable; this should work for cases where you do not control the code that's calling the oauth library.

[Here's where that's implemented in the oauthlib library.](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib/blob/564d526fdbdc32a936e4b5ddac186c26024f626b/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py#L466)

Comment: It works! What would be the security implications of using this flag?

Comment: The authorized scopes could be different from what was requested. Functionally there could be a problem if _fewer_ scopes are granted than what were requested. Security-wise you don't necessarily want _more_ scopes granted but that's exactly what `include_granted_scopes=True` does in Google's library: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#incrementalAuth

Comment: So what's the proper way if you DO control the code that's calling the oauth library?

Comment: Using FastAPI, I noticed that catching the `Warning` object and printing it, would only print `Scope has changed from... etc.`, while using `jsonable_encoder` returns the whole credentials object, with old and new scopes. So I ended up catching the `Warning`, returning the json encoded warning as a response. I'm guessing that's how they intended it to work?

Answer (score 11):

I was able to bypass the problem by setting the scopes to `None` in the callback function.

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
        scopes=None,
        redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
    )
flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
```

Comment: I got an error page from Google when I tried this approach saying that `scopes` must be defined

Answer (score 8):

All the previous answers didn't worked for me. I solved it by adding this line :

```
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'
```

Answer (score 6):

Even I also had the same issue. I have fixed this by removing `include_granted_scopes='true',` in the flow.authorization_url

Comment: I tried removing `include_granted_scopes='true'` also tried setting it to `false` but it didn't help. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know it that's the error, but scopes should be maybe list scopes instead of one string - change this:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
        )
```

To this:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
            scopes=[
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs', 
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

I added the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` to where I create my `Flow` objects:

```
Flow.from_client_config(
    secrets_json_string,
    scopes=[
        (…),
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    ],
    redirect_uri=redirect_url
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the same error even after including `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` in the flow scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `include_granted_scopes='true'` so scopes will be append when you run again.

Let's set `include_granted_scopes='false'`