# Google & Oauthlib - Scope has changed with InstalledAppFlow

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I have the following code:

```
appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    "client_secret.json", scopes=scopes
)

appflow.run_local_server()

credentials = appflow.credentials
```

But it raises this error:

```
Warning: Scope has changed from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose".
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499034/google-oauthlib-scope-has-changed), but the error raises when calling a different method, so the answers don't apply to my case.

Can't find how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the error message was pretty straightforward: I basically had to replace deprecated scopes entries with the new ones, indicated in the error message:

original `scopes`:

```
scopes = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose']
```

New `scopes`:

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose']
```