# google oauth fetch_token failing

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm trying to implement google OAuth flow using the guide from the google dev console.
however, the code fails at the fetch_token block in the code and I'm unable to move forward.

Hey 
I'm trying to implement google OAuth flow using the guide from the google dev console.
however, the code fails at the fetch_token block in the code and I'm unable to move forward.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline

```
import flask,os
import requests
import waitress
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
from urllib import parse


# This variable specifies the name of a file that contains the OAuth 2.0
# information for this application, including its client_id and client_secret.
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account and requires requests to use an SSL connection.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
# Note: A secret key is included in the sample so that it works.
# If you use this code in your application, replace this with a truly secret
# key. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/quickstart/#sessions.
app.secret_key = 'REPLACE ME - this value is here as a placeholder.'


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return print_index_table()


@app.route('/test')
def test_api_request():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect('authorize')

  # Load credentials from the session.
  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
      **flask.session['credentials'])

  drive = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
      API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

  files = drive.files().list().execute()

  # Save credentials back to session in case access token was refreshed.
  # ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save these
  #              credentials in a persistent database instead.
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  return flask.jsonify(**files)


@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
  # Create flow instance to manage the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grant Flow steps.
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  # The URI created here must exactly match one of the authorized redirect URIs
  # for the OAuth 2.0 client, which you configured in the API Console. If this
  # value doesn't match an authorized URI, you will get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch'
  # error.
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
      # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
      access_type='offline',
      # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
      include_granted_scopes='true')

  # Store the state so the callback can verify the auth server response.
  flask.session['state'] = state

  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
  # Specify the state when creating the flow in the callback so that it can
  # verified in the authorization server response.
  state = flask.session['state']

  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  # Use the authorization server's response to fetch the OAuth 2.0 tokens.
  authorization_response = flask.request.url
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

  # Store credentials in the session.
  # ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save these
  #              credentials in a persistent database instead.
  credentials = flow.credentials
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('test_api_request'))


@app.route('/revoke')
def revoke():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return ('You need to <a href="/authorize">authorize</a> before ' +
            'testing the code to revoke credentials.')

  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    **flask.session['credentials'])

  revoke = requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke',
      params={'token': credentials.token},
      headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

  status_code = getattr(revoke, 'status_code')
  if status_code == 200:
    return('Credentials successfully revoked.' + print_index_table())
  else:
    return('An error occurred.' + print_index_table())


@app.route('/clear')
def clear_credentials():
  if 'credentials' in flask.session:
    del flask.session['credentials']
  return ('Credentials have been cleared.<br><br>' +
          print_index_table())


def credentials_to_dict(credentials):
  return {'token': credentials.token,
          'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
          'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
          'client_id': credentials.client_id,
          'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
          'scopes': credentials.scopes}

def print_index_table():
  return ('<table>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/test">Test an API request</a></td>' +
          '<td>Submit an API request and see a formatted JSON response. ' +
          '    Go through the authorization flow if there are no stored ' +
          '    credentials for the user.</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/authorize">Test the auth flow directly</a></td>' +
          '<td>Go directly to the authorization flow. If there are stored ' +
          '    credentials, you still might not be prompted to reauthorize ' +
          '    the application.</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/revoke">Revoke current credentials</a></td>' +
          '<td>Revoke the access token associated with the current user ' +
          '    session. After revoking credentials, if you go to the test ' +
          '    page, you should see an <code>invalid_grant</code> error.' +
          '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/clear">Clear Flask session credentials</a></td>' +
          '<td>Clear the access token currently stored in the user session. ' +
          '    After clearing the token, if you <a href="/test">test the ' +
          '    API request</a> again, you should go back to the auth flow.' +
          '</td></tr></table>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification.
  # ACTION ITEM for developers:
  #     When running in production *do not* leave this option enabled.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

  # Specify a hostname and port that are set as a valid redirect URI
  # for your API project in the Google API Console.
  waitress.serve(app, port="8080", url_scheme="https")
```

console.log

```
ERROR:main:Exception on /oauth2callback [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "main.py", line 91, in oauth2callback
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 288, in fetch_token
    return self.oauth2session.fetch_token(self.client_config["token_uri"], **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 360, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py", line 429, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 425, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 455, in validate_token_parameters
    raise w
Warning: Scope has changed from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly".
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for this, the answer is here:

[Google & Oauthlib - Scope has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499034/google-oauthlib-scope-has-changed/51643134#51643134)

You can disable this warning by setting the OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE environment variable; this should work for cases where you do not control the code that's calling the oauth library.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you are running this on your local machine (you have disabled HTTPs verification). If so, then I don't think your `url_scheme="https"` is correct. It should be set to `http`
2. You also have this

`Warning: Scope has changed from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly".`

This means that the scope in your credentials file is different from what you have in your code. You should get them to be the same

Comment: I'm running this on replit and I cannot set the url_scheme to 'http' as the scope are sensitive.

the code fails in the line flow.fetch_token