# Can not build Using Google OAuth2 with Flask by Requests-OAuthlib

Tags: flask, google-api, google-signin, flask-login, requests-oauthlib

I try build gooogle login with flask login.
I find the thread here
[Using Google OAuth2 with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499286/using-google-oauth2-with-flask)

> I was able to port the accepted answer to use Requests-OAuthlib instead of Rauth. As of this writing, the package's last commit was on June 2019 and was currently use by 30K+ repositories.

the **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
import dir
from flask_mail import Mail

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()
mail = Mail()

GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID = "mygoogle API id .apps.googleusercontent.com" #I am sure It is correct
GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET = "my_secret_key"
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = True
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key-goes-here'

    # app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////' + str(dir.dir) + '/admin.sqlite'
    app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
    app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'ruaxe.sdafsafsafs'
    app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'uiykejafsaffiqklziccld'
    app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
    app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
    app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS']  = {
        'google': {
            'id': GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID,
            'secret': GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET
        }
    }
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    from .models import User
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))



    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)


    return app
```

Then i build the auth.py with login page

```
auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    if current_user is not None and current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

the user view page i build in main.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, flash, url_for, current_app
from flask_login import login_required, current_user,login_user
from project.function import cmsHaravan as hara, cmsCalendar as cal
from .function import config as cf, cmsContacts as ct
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from .models import User, Order, Shop
from . import db, mail
from flask_mail import Message
import random
import string
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from urllib.request import urlopen

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

class OAuthSignIn(object):
    providers = None

    def __init__(self, provider_name):
        self.provider_name = provider_name
        credentials = current_app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS'][provider_name]
        self.consumer_id = credentials['id']
        self.consumer_secret = credentials['secret']

    def authorize(self):
        pass

    def callback(self):
        pass

    def get_callback_url(self):
        return url_for('main.profile', provider=self.provider_name,
                        _external=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_provider(self, provider_name):
        if self.providers is None:
            self.providers={}
            for provider_class in self.__subclasses__():
                provider = provider_class()
                self.providers[provider.provider_name] = provider
        return self.providers[provider_name]

class GoogleSignIn(OAuthSignIn):
    openid_url = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
    def __init__(self):
        super(GoogleSignIn, self).__init__("google")
        self.openid_config = json.load(urlopen(self.openid_url))
        self.session = OAuth2Session(
            client_id=self.consumer_id,
            redirect_uri=self.get_callback_url(),
            scope=self.openid_config["scopes_supported"]
        )

    def authorize(self):
        auth_url, _ = self.session.authorization_url(
            self.openid_config["authorization_endpoint"])
        print(auth_url)
        return redirect(auth_url)

    def callback(self):
        if "code" not in request.args:
            return None, None

        self.session.fetch_token(
            token_url=self.openid_config["token_endpoint"],
            code=request.args["code"],
            client_secret=self.consumer_secret,
        )

        me = self.session.get(self.openid_config["userinfo_endpoint"]).json()
        print(me)
        print(me["name"], me["email"])
        return me["name"], me["email"]
@main.route('/authorize/<provider>')
def oauth_authorize(provider):
    # Flask-Login function
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    return oauth.authorize()

@main.route('/profile/<provider>')
def oauth_callback(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    name, email = oauth.callback()
    print("da lay duoc email", email)
    if email is None:
        # I need a valid email address for my user identification
        flash('Authentication failed.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    # Look if the user already exists
    user=User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if not user:
        # Create the user. Try and use their name returned by Google,
        # but if it is not set, split the email address at the @.
        name = name
        if name is None or name == "":
            name = email.split('@')[0]

        # We can do more work here to ensure a unique nickname, if you
        # require that.
        user=User(firstname=name, email=email)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    # Log in the user, by default remembering them for their next visit
    # unless they log out.
    login_user(user, remember=True)
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))


@main.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    ListCarBrands = cal.getListCarBrands()
    ListProvinces = cal.getListProvinces()
    order_email = current_user.email
    list_order = {}
    i = 0
    for row in Order.query.filter_by(order_email=order_email):
        i = i + 1
        total_order = i
        list_order[i] = row.__dict__
    return render_template('profile.html', list_order=list_order, name=current_user.lastname,
                           biensoxe=current_user.biensoxe,
                           ListCarBrands=ListCarBrands, brands=current_user.brands, carclass=current_user.carclass,
                           firstname=current_user.firstname, lastname=current_user.lastname, phone=current_user.phone,
                           email=current_user.email, ListProvinces=ListProvinces, provinces=current_user.provinces)
```

The login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
     <div id="sign-in">
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <p>
        <a href={{ url_for('main.oauth_authorize', provider='google') }}><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/sign-in-with-google.png') }}" /></a>
    </div>

    <form method="POST" action="/login">
        <div class="ui-information-body">
            <div class="align-content-center">
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                    {% if messages %}
                        <div class="notification is-danger">
                            {{ messages[0] }}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
                <h4>Login {{ error }}</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5 "><label class="label-input-group">Email </label><input type="email"
                                                                                              class="next-input"
                                                                                              name="email" id="email"
                                                                                              value=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-5 "><label class="label-input-group">Password</label><input type="password"
                                                                                                class="next-input"
                                                                                                name="password"
                                                                                                id="password"
                                                                                                value=""></div>


                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5 "><span class="label-input-group"><br></span>
                        <a href="{{ url_for('main.reset_password') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
                            Nếu bạn quên mật khẩu? Reset
                        </a></div>


                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5 "><span class="label-input-group"><br></span><input
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Login"></div>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Profile html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" action="/profile">
        Some code here for user can update profile
    </form>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Then i run program, i can get the link as the code in

```
    def authorize(self):
        auth_url, _ = self.session.authorization_url(
            self.openid_config["authorization_endpoint"])
        print(auth_url) ##### This function run
        return redirect(auth_url)
```

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=880298757050-ij79mostsm1fccdcvuj43m0oe0quisih.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fprofile%3Fprovider%3Dgoogle&scope=openid+email+profile&state=xwbrUEpMjhIFrM6l3PlXgcXdgzyDbd
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2020 14:03:32] "GET /authorize/google HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2020 14:03:35] "GET /profile?provider=google&state=xwbrUEpMjhIFrM6l3PlXgcXdgzyDbd&code=4%2F3QFTG6I2FzBPUKD_Sk0hq4IUhlr0jA4EQ2fTLyQizyYsPkCLxRf_WXwQz929v4wUeJhN4IXWFWu7nLKBJ2NHhog&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=0&prompt=consent HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2020 14:03:35] "GET /login?next=%2Fprofile%3Fprovider%3Dgoogle%26state%3DxwbrUEpMjhIFrM6l3PlXgcXdgzyDbd%26code%3D4%252F3QFTG6I2FzBPUKD_Sk0hq4IUhlr0jA4EQ2fTLyQizyYsPkCLxRf_WXwQz929v4wUeJhN4IXWFWu7nLKBJ2NHhog%26scope%3Demail%2Bprofile%2Bopenid%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fuserinfo.email%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fuserinfo.profile%26authuser%3D0%26prompt%3Dconsent HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2020 14:03:35] "GET /static/img/sign-in-with-google.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2020 14:03:35] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

BUT I TRY TO PRINT EMAIL AS THE CODE in route profile

```
oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    name, email = oauth.callback()
    print("da lay duoc email", email)
```

**Nothing come!** So anyone can help me
**Thanks to all**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all
I change scope and it run!

```
class GoogleSignIn(OAuthSignIn):
    openid_url = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
    def __init__(self):
        super(GoogleSignIn, self).__init__("google")
        self.openid_config = json.load(urlopen(self.openid_url))
        self.session = OAuth2Session(
            client_id=self.consumer_id,
            redirect_uri=self.get_callback_url(),
            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        )
```